# Python If statement not branching correctly

Tags: python-3.x

The if statement within one of my functions isn't branching the way I am expecting and I can't figure out what I am doing incorrectly.  Any help is appreciated.

```
def getStockList (dbCursor, **kwargs)   :

    returnList = {}
    pastDue = False
    for key in kwargs :
        if key == 'past_due' : 
            pastDue = kwargs[key]
            print ('pastDue before if statement =',pastDue)
            if pastDue == True :
                print ('retrieving past due stocks')
                # ... code removed for simplicity
            else:
                print ('retrieving all stocks')
                # ... code removed for simplicity

    print ('pastDue at end =',pastDue)
    return returnList
```

The output is this...

```
pastDue before if statement = True

retrieving all stocks

pastDue at end = True
```

Comment: Isn't the value you take from your kwargs the string 'True' instead of the boolean `True`?

Comment: Thanks Thierry!   I was calling the function with a str instead of boolean.   :-).   I guess what confused me was that I thought pastDue was being typed as boolean with it's initialization to False at the beginning.   I didn't realize that a variable could have different types within the same function.  I am a Python newbie.